# Too many GET requests for Facebook like buttons for a list of items

Tags: performance, facebook, facebook-like, privacy

I have 30 `facebook like` buttons for a list of 30 items on single page. This leads to 30 GET requests, each for a button.

Is there a way I could reduce the no of GET requests?

Also request take too long and sometimes even fail thus rendering the page without like button. At times request are not even triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load them based on scroll position like sites like Techcrunch do. [This site](http://cyrilmazur.com/2011/08/deferred-lazy-loading-facebook-widgets.html) has a walkthrough on how to do it. But if all 30 buttons need to be displayed all at once then this will be hard to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but one may also use the "[2-click Social Buttons (like,google +1,tweeter...)](http://www.furidamu.org/blog/2012/03/15/better-privacy-with-2-click-social-buttons/)" solution to gain 2 benefits:

- privacy
- performance

also see:
https://www.google.co.il/search?q=social+share+privacy